# Why pre_task on Ansible validates ansible_python_version to 2.7 and then to 3.6

Tags: python, ansible

On my playbook I am trying to validate the Python version. On this OS (Linux) I have two versions of Python:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.5

python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

I set a pre_task to validate the Ansible version and also the Python version (sample):

```
pre_tasks:
    - name: Validate we run with the correct Ansible version
      register: data
      assert:
        that:
          - ansible_version is defined
          - ansible_version.full is version('2.8.0.0', '>=')
          - ansible_python_version is defined
          - ansible_python_version is version('3.6.0', '>=')
        fail_msg: "'Python' version must be 3.6.0 and Ansible 2.8.0 minimal version."
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Get facts
      register: facts
      setup:
        filter: ansible_python_version
      run_once: true

    - name: Debug facts
      debug:
        var: facts
```

Unfortunately when I run this role it fails as it seems to be first reading the Python2 and then Python3.

Important to mention here is that I have removed Ansible for Python2 sample:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.1
  config file = /ripl-nginx/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

When I execute the pre_task it fails as following:

```
fatal: [hostname -> localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "ansible_python_version is version('3.6.0', '>=')",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "'Python' version must be 3.6.0 and Ansible 2.8.0 minimal version."
}
```

If I modify the validation to 2.7.5 e.g.:

```
- ansible_python_version is version('2.7.5', '>=')
```

It works perfectly:

```
ok: [hostname] => {
    "facts": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "ansible_python_version": "3.6.8"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

What I have noticed is that if I remove the `delegate_to: localhost` parameter it first finds the Python2 which I assume is the reason that is failing (sample):

```
pre_tasks:
    - name: Validate we run with the correct Ansible version
      register: data
      assert:
        that:
          - ansible_version is defined
          - ansible_version.full is version('2.8.0.0', '>=')
          - ansible_python_version is defined
          - ansible_python_version is version('2.7.5', '>=')
        fail_msg: "'Python' version must be 3.6.0 and Ansible 2.8.0 minimal version."
      run_once: true

    - name: Get facts
      register: facts
      setup:
        filter: ansible_python_version
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Debug facts
      debug:
        var: facts
```

Output:

```
ok: [hostname] => {
    "facts": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "ansible_python_version": "2.7.5"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or I am missing a configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem (in case you have set up your group vars as `ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3`):

```
pre_tasks:
    - name: Validate we run with the correct Ansible version
      delegate_to: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_python_version']
      assert:
        that:
          - ansible_version is defined
          - ansible_version.full is version('2.8.0.0', '>=')
          - ansible_python_version is defined
          - ansible_python_version is version('3.6.0', '>=')
        fail_msg: "'Python' version must be 3.6.0 and Ansible 2.8.0 minimal version."
      run_once: True
```

Sample of output:

```
TASK [Validate we run with the correct Ansible version] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname -> hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_python_version']] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [Debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_python_version']": "3.6.8"
}
```

If preferred way is to have the global configuration for the interpreter can be done like in the main ansible.cfg under [defaults] e.g.:

```
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3
```

Remember you can not have both defined. Either the global on the ansible.cfg file or then for each environment. For more information read the official documentation ([Interpreter Discovery](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html)).